# Nlogo file refusing to open - error message "File is not a valid Netlogo model file"

Tags: file, netlogo

Please please can someone help me.  I have been working on a netlogo model for weeks and yesterday saved my latest version as `Glen Creran1.nlogo`.  Today when I go to open it I get the message

> File is not a valid Netlogo model file.

Earlier versions of the same file are opening fine (such as Glen Creran.nlogo).  I dont understand what is going on.
Please please can someone help. I have worked so hard on this code.... 
Any suggestions very welcome - maybe I can find a backup somewhere?
Many thanks,
Sally.

Comment: Apparently you have old versions.  Are any recent?  If so, you can use a file-compare (diff) utility to see what was changed.      This really should not happen if you are using the NetLogo editor.  Were you editing the file in an external editor?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Model-file-format has a full explanation of all things that are required in a netlogo model file. Try to look through that and see if something is missing (I'm almost certain it is).

Alternatively, try to open the netlogo file in a text editor and copy/paste its contents to here, and we can try to help you out.